# Laravel ajax URL return 404 error in live and workign perfectly in local

Tags: ajax, laravel

Where it goes wrong . this is my code for ajax

```
    $('.statusUpdate').click(function(){
    var update_id = $(this).attr('rel');
    var toggle_class = $(this).find('i').attr('class');
    var status = (toggle_class == 'fa fa-toggle-off')? 'Y':'N';        
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/menugroup/update",
        data: {'id':update_id,'status':status},
    })
    .done(function(response){
            if(response == 'success'){
                update_class = (status=='Y')? 'fa fa-toggle-on':'fa fa-toggle-off';
                $('#status_'+update_id).find('i').attr('class',update_class);
            }
    });
});
```

In the router I have used

```
Route::post('/menugroup/update','MenugroupController@update');
```

In local it is working fine on click generate

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

http://127.0.0.1:8000/menugroup/update

But in live the project is placed in folder dinesapp

```
APP_URL=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/dinesapp
```

And on ajax request on live network tab shows  http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/menugroup/update
instead of http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/dinesapp/menugroup/update which in turn return 404 error in Laravel. Is there any base path to be configured in Laravel?

Comment: You have to configure your server according to your URL. 
your project is in `dinesapp` folder then make that folder as a root folder

Comment: where we have to configure, is there any configuration In .env  file . I have set the APP_URL=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/dinesapp.

Comment: you have to configure the server (apache or nginx) config file  `dinesapp` make this folder as a root folder. after that, you can access just using `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` from `dinesapp` folder

Comment: Read this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-application-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one thing to solve this issue:

Define the base url in head section :

```
<script>
   var base_url = '{{ URL::to("/") }}';
</script>
```

And then call ajax like this :

```
$('.statusUpdate').click(function(){
    var update_id = $(this).attr('rel');
    var toggle_class = $(this).find('i').attr('class');
    var status = (toggle_class == 'fa fa-toggle-off')? 'Y':'N';        
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base_url +"menugroup/update",
        data: {'id':update_id,'status':status},
    })
    .done(function(response){
            if(response == 'success'){
                update_class = (status=='Y')? 'fa fa-toggle-on':'fa fa-toggle-off';
                $('#status_'+update_id).find('i').attr('class',update_class);
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have checked, Its not working as the Laravel works for only  Route::post('/menugroup/update','MenugroupController@update');

Comment: it is working fine in local but on live network tab shows http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/menugroup/update instead of http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/dinesapp/menugroup/update                                                  which in turn return 404 error in Laravel. Is there any base path to be configured in Laravel?

Comment: Can you please share route for the home page

Comment: @AnoopPS it's in the .env file, APP_URL variable. And your issue is more related to absolute & relative links than to laravel. even if the .env doesnt fix your issue, you can make a custom config variable to fix it

Comment: APP_URL=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/dinesapp/

Comment: Hi jaimain I got it , I just replaced the ajax call backward slash from the front  url: menugroup/update",

Comment: Yes, that is also the issue. But as per the standard way if use base url than it will be good practice. If you can make change in .env file to APP_URL=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/dinesapp/ and than try my code, it will also solve the problem.

Comment: Adding  url: APP_URL+"menugroup/update"  works fine

Answer (score 0):

I got it the issue is the front slash

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/menugroup/update",
    data: {'id':update_id,'status':status},
})
```

the below code worked.  How comes it happens when the base url change
 when we add a slash in front

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "menugroup/update",
    data: {'id':update_id,'status':status},
})
```